# How to send additional data to the template when Django ValidationError occurred on a specific field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, autosuggest, validationerror

Let us say, I have a Django Form - XYZ which had fields A, B, C. Field B is username field, when a particular username already exists, Validation Error occurs and throws back a message. Along with that I want to send some auto-suggested username-dict to the template. 
As per my understanding, i can only send as Field Errors and Non-Field errors.

```
def clean_B(self):
        B = self.cleaned_data['B']
        if address.objects.filter(B=B).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exists")
        return B
```

I tried to add another error using Form.add_error() and Django doesn't allow multiple errors in a single dict per field or Non_field errors.

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you add that to the message for current `ValidationError`? You could do whatever you like to the `cleaned_data` to generate some suggestions, and do: `raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exists, please try foo, bar or baz instead")`.

Comment: I would like to make it more user friendly (Some thing like Gmail Auto Suggest). Users can just click on "foo"/"bar", so that it can be filled in the username field!! Error Message is different and Suggestions is different!!

For that, i need the Auto Suggestions in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `django messages framework` to show your message with suggestions to user.

```
from django.contrib import messages

...

def clean_B(self):
    B = self.cleaned_data['B']
    if address.objects.filter(B=B).exists():
        # In __init__ method of the form, you should store request as property
        messages.info(self.request, 'You should use another username, i.e. John')
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username already exists')
    return B
```

And then, somewhere in your template, output message:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Astrikov,

Thanks for the answer, it makes sense to use messages here. But unable to get the request data into the clean_B function. and Is it the good practice available in this scenario.

Error:

AttributeError: 'XYZCreateForm' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: As I said, you should pass `request` to your `form kwargs` and store it as property in your `__init__` method

Comment: Hi Astrikov,

While your suggestion solves the major problem, Am unable to send "dict"/json of available usernames in the message, Message is just converted to string! I need to perform some clickable function on the template side, its only possible if the message is dict/json.

It's throwing some crazy errors when using ast.literal_eval(). Is there a way to directly send json or dict to the template as message or error?